# “L’on y danse”: why the article “l’ ”?

Tags: pronoms, articles, euphonie

> Sur le pont d'Avignon, l'on y danse tous en rond.

What is *l'* doing here? When is it generally used like this?

I'm assuming it's a pronoun, but *y* already refers to *pont*, so it's not quite like *je l'ai vu* — or is it? I've seen it a lot in novels too. I've asked a Frenchman this question but he couldn't tell me out of hand.

Comment: à vrai dire je n'ai pas trouvé de source pour le confirmer…

Comment: @Knu: Je me sens comme tournant tout en rond: Wikipedia anglaise a *tous*, mais la française a *tout*! Quoi croire?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the *l* added in front of *“on”* generally does not have a particular grammatical purpose: it is purely euphonic, and a sign of polished language (it softens the otherwise familiar overtones of using *"on"*).

It is more often added when *“on”* does not start a proposition, such as when introduced by a conjunction:

> Il faut que l'on y aille.

instead of:

> Il faut qu'on y aille.

In such cases, the euphonic use is a lot more obvious due to the bad association of the sound *“qu'on”* in French.

In this present case, I would say poetic license, and the will to avoid a disharmonious collision between *“pont”* and *“on”*, are the reasons for adding that euphonic *l*.

As for the origin of this *l* (and why it is not *t*), the [French Wikipedia entry on *phonème éphelcystique*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Phon%C3%A8me_%C3%A9phelcystique) tells us:

> [...] le [l] qui précède parfois le pronom personnel indéfini *on* en début de phrase ou devant voyelle (ex. : « Ici l'on fume, ici l'on chante, ici l'on dort. », L'Auberge, Paul Verlaine, « L'on prétend que… ») est pleinement étymologique. Il s'est effectivement conservé dans des contextes littéraires, peut-être pour des raisons euphoniques, mais c'est le vestige de l'article défini qui précédait le on substantif (ancien français *on*, *om* ou *hom*, « homme », du nominatif latin *homo*). De même, dans « aide-t'en », « va-t'en », « rapproche-t'en », etc., le *t* correspond au pronom de la deuxième personne, *te*, élidé devant voyelle.

It is indeed a relic of the definite article *le* (whereas *t* comes from *“te”*).

Comment: Hah, *qu'on* sounds rather inappropriate indeed, never thought about that. Thanks for your explanation. Any reason why *l* was chosen instead of *t*, as in *a-t-il*? And is it never *le* in any other sentence, i.e. does it only ever occur before a vowel?

Comment: @Cerberus: added a wikipedia citation that gives the origin of both "l" and "t".

Comment: Ahh merci beaucoup! That makes sense. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had no idea the *t* came from *te*, very interesting.

Comment: No, the "l" is not euphonic in that case. It does make pronunciation in the least easier, quite the opposite since it adds an extra vowel.

Answer (score 23):

Je recommande la lecture de ce [petit article](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/et-lon) sur « on » et « l'on ». On y trouve la réponse à la question, l'origine de cette construction, et les cas dans lesquels il convient de l'employer.

Petit extrait choisi :

> Le *l* apostrophe de *l'on* n'est pas à l'origine une consonne euphonique,
>   mais l'article défini : *l'on* était synonyme de *l'homme* en général. Au
>   fil des siècles, ce nom on s'est transformé en véritable pronom
>   indéfini (désignant un individu non déterminé) et son article défini
>   est devenu facultatif. Cette évolution pourrait se schématiser avec
>   ces trois exemples :
>
> *L'homme est bien peu de chose.*
>     *L'on est bien peu de chose.*
>     *On est bien peu de chose.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Your answer is just as good as Dave's, and your link in fact provides even more information—exactly what I needed! I've already ticked his answer off as accepted, but you both deserve ticks!

Comment: @Cerberus One would expect three-headed ticks from someone like you but... ;-)

Comment: @RomainVALERI: If I had more than one tick mark to give out, I would give you one! But, alas, I cannot take away the one I already gave to Dave. And he needs it more, given his lower score...

Comment: @Cerberus Sorry, just a lame pun attempt around Cerberus (the mythical dog) and *ticks* ... I'm just slightly ashamed I admit.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: Ohh you mean the arthropod haha. Got it! But, no, my ticks are my nemeses; they do not share my noble polycephaly!

Answer (score 2):

Le `L` est ici purement esthétique.

**J'espère qu'on a fini.** = **J'espère que l'on a fini.**

(Cette phrase est cependant différente de **J'espère qu'on l'a fini.**)

Answer (score 2):

Le pronom « on » a déjà été assimilé à un *nom* vu son [origine](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1044/3177), et a conservé à l'écrit la possibilité d'avoir l'article défini; et c'était important car ces grammairiens avaient peur du [*hiatus*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hiatus) possible avec *et*, *ou*, *où*, *quoi*, *si* et de l'[homophonie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/homophonie) dans le cas de *que*, sans l'article, de sorte que l'on a parfois jugé que c'était même requis. On peut illustrer :

> *Ce qu'on propose... c'est de passer au vote, et on insiste.*
>  *Ce
>   con propose... de tout foutre en l'air.*
>  *Ce qu'ont proposé ces gens,
>   c'est qu'on... vote.*
>
> *Ce que l'on propose, c'est que l'on vote.*

On en voit l'utilité, mais l'utiliser reste un **choix** (par exemple, voir un emploi empreint de *liberté* présenté dans *Le Bon Usage* (note *R2*, au par. 754) apparaissant directement au dictionnaire de l'*Académie* (9ème), à l'entrée [*fin*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/fin):[...] « *Ce qu'on se propose pour but, résultat que l'on poursuit.* ». Ça s'utilise aussi en tête de phrase sans difficulté (l'extrait présenté apparaît usuellement sur deux lignes) : « *L'on comprend que lorsqu'il se tait, c'est pour penser*. » (Gide, *Thésée*).

> Pour l'[euphonie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/euphonie), les grammairiens conseillent d'éviter *l'on* après
>   *dont* ou devant un mot commençant par [l] et de l'employer après *que* si la syllabe qui suit est [kɔ̃]. Mais si la première prescription (après *dont*) est assez bien respectée, les manquements
>   aux deux autres sont loin d'être rares:
>
> [...] *CE QU'ON CONCÉDERAIT à la vérité* (Camus, *Homme révolté*, p. 233). [...]
>
> [ *Le Bon Usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, *ed. De Boeck/Duculot*, par. **754 f)**
>   ]

Je ne crois pas que ce soit un style ou un procédé littéraire; tel qu'on l'indique dans la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1030/3177), il s'agit de vestiges de l'histoire de la langue française.<sup>1</sup> Dans l'oeuvre [*Sur le pont d'Avignon*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sur_le_pont_d%27Avignon), on peut noter qu'on a déjà eu [aussi](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Sur_le_pont_d%27Avignon_19th.jpg) « *Tout le monde y danse, y danse* » où l'article est présent. Personnellement, j'entends le refrain dans mon esprit sans le « l'»; et toujours à mon avis, l'entendre rappelle le « que », absent, et me donne une impression d'ampleur (tant), et de lieu (où).

---

<sub>1. On lira avec intérêt les paragraphes 753 et 754, avec tous les exemples et contre-exemples, dans *Le Bon Usage*. Je le paraphrase amplement ici; en ancien et moyen français on avait avant le 17ème (avec son « t ») : « *tant crie *l'on* Noël qu'il vient*. » (Villon, *Poèmes variés*). Pour situer, à cette époque-là, [*Vaugelas*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Favre_de_Vaugelas) écrit (*LBU*, note *H2*, par. 684) : « *Je ne le veux pas faire*, sera meilleur que *je ne veux pas le faire* parce qu'il est incomparablement plus usité. » Il faut voir, à mon avis, que les temps ont bien changé mais que la richesse demeure. On notera que A. Goosse a écrit : *Les emplois modernes de* l'on, dans *Mélanges de grammaire et de lexicologie française*, pp. 1-37 !</sub>

Comment: Très bon, quelle nuance! Merci.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because "on" follows "Avignon", which would put two "on" sounds in a row, which is difficult to say without running them together. This is mitigated when sung in the context of the song as there is a pause between the two words.  But read in a speaking voice there would easily be that blurring of articulation without the "l'on".