# Quand est-ce qu'on écrit « l'on » dans les textes

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, orthographe, euphonie

Je viens de remarquer dans mon livre de grammaire ce qui, je pense, est une erreur. Ça concerne la façon dont on écrit « on » dans une phrase. Je pense à la règle d'écriture (formelle) :

> Si le dernier mot avant "on" se termine avec une voyelle, il faut écrire "l'on" au lieu de "on".

Par exemple, prenez la phrase suivante :

> Il est cependant indispensable de savoir au moins reconnaitre ces deux temps aujourd'hui en décadence, **que l'on** rencontre souvent chez les écrivains classiques.

Celle-là suit bien la règle. Mais prenez ces deux phrases, on voit bien une différence :

> **Comme on** le voit, la plupart des verbes pronominaux se traduisent en anglais au moyen de *reflexive pronouns*.
>
> **Ainsi on** dira autre chose.

Les deux phrases qui ne suivent pas la règle n'ont rien d'unique (que je puisse voir). La seule chose qui peut poser un problème de prononciation est « *comme on le voit* ». Si on suit la règle, ça deviendrait « *comme l'on le voit* », une phrase qui peut être difficile à prononcer.

Toutes ces phrases viennent du même livre. Est-ce une orthographe correcte et, si oui, quelle est la règle ? Ou est-ce une erreur des auteurs ? Ou bien, est-ce une chose qu'on fait n'importe quand dans les textes écrits ?

Comment: Peut-être un doublon : [L’on y danse”: why the article “l’ ”?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/lon-y-danse-why-the-article-l). Et ne pas manquer l'article en lien dans la réponse de Stéphane Gimenez.

Comment: Oui c'est un doublon, je suis désolé. J'ai cherché le site, mais je ne pourrais pas le trouver! Merci :)

Comment: Je t'ai laissé un message sur le chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14235502#14235502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*L'on* existe parce que ce mot a été un nom commun (au sens d'"homme") avant de devenir un pronom. Bien que l'euphonie entre parfois en jeu,<sup>(1)</sup> ce n'est pas l'origine de cette consonne, qui ne peut pas être comparée, disons, au "ne explétif".

Grammaticalement et syntactiquement, **il n'y a aucune règle précise et réellement fonctionnelle régissant son usage par rapport à on seul** (Grevisse, Le Bon Usage, 14e éd., §754 f). Les auteurs l'emploie en variation libre (quoiqu'il s'agisse souvent d'un usage un peu plus relevé) selon leurs goûts.

(1) Les grammaires classiques recommandent souvent, pas nécessairement avec succès, d'écrire *que l'on* plutôt que *qu'on* à cause de l'homophone.