# "Lorsqu'on" ou "lorsque l'on"

Tags: usage

L'outil *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lorsqu%27on%2C+lorsque+l%27on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clorsqu%27on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clorsque%20l%27%20on%3B%2Cc0)<sup>1</sup>* est sans pitié, il favorise *lorsqu'on*.

Mon correcteur d'orthographe voit rouge, il refuse ces familiarités.

1°) Coupable de l'utiliser à l'oral, j'aimerais savoir quelle est l'origine de cette règle.

2°) Mais pourquoi accepte-il *lorsqu'il, lorsqu'en, lorsqu'un* ? Quelles sont donc les règles d'utilisation de *lorsqu'* et de *lorsque* ?

---

<sup>1 -  si l'on ajoute *lorsque on* (qui renvoie très peu de résultat) le lien de fonctionne plus,</sup>

Comment: La note sur [la page du Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%E2%80%99on#Pronom_personnel) dit simplement que _l'on_ est considéré plus soutenu qu'_on_. D'autres résultats de ma recherche ont la même explication que [Guillaume](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17340/7224).

Comment: Peut-être c’est compris dans la notion de « malsonnant » (qui figure souvent dans le lien cité dans la réponse de guillaume) mais j’évite « qu’on » pour éviter d’être accusé de « traiter de con » quelqu’un qui ne le mérite pas.  En général, je réserve mes « cons » pour les vrais, pas les faucons!

Comment: @PapaPoule - J'y ai bien pensé, mais je me rends compte que précédé de `lorssseu`, on oublie ce tendre mot que Brassens chante dans *Le Blason*. Il faut y penser avant et tourner sa phrase savamment pour faire apparaître le sens que vous évoquez : `lors ce qu'on`. C'est ce qui m'a surpris dans le Ngram qui, en principe, est établi sur des textes plutôt soutenus.

Comment: Aussi [ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1029/3177) !

Comment: @PapaPoule Une façon commode d'éviter « lorsqu'on », c'est d'employer « quand on ». L'avantage est que c'est aussi peu soutenu, voire encore moins (on évite ainsi, à l'oral courant, de passer pour un snob). D'un autre côté, il y a bien toujours une consonnace ambigüe, mais dont l'aspect sobrement administratif ne peut vexer personne !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Lorsqu'on* ou *Lorsque l'on* sont corrects tous les deux, à l'écrit comme à l'oral.**

L'on est toutefois plus stylé.

Cette forme avec *l'on* à la suite d'une voyelle (*que,si*), à la place de *qu'on, si on* est spécifique, et ne s'utilise pas avec il ou elle par exemple.

Son origine vient de *l'homme*, qui a donné *l'on*, puis *on* selon cette référence: https://www.druide.com/enquetes/et-lon

Origine **homme**:

> Du lat. homo, cas suj. du subst. signifiant «homme», développé en
>   position proclitique, et qui, à basse époque, est relevé dans qq. ex.
>   comme suj. indéterm., emploi aboutissant à sa fonction de pron. indéf.

Usage de **l'article défini**:

> employé avec l'art. déf. ca 1050 disjoint, précède le verbe dont il
>   est le suj. (St Alexis, éd. Chr. Storey, 566: Sainz Boneface, que l'um
>   martir apelet);

L'étymologie détaillée peut être trouvée ici:
http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?19;s=869070855;r=1;nat=;sol=8;

Comment: Les enquêtes linguistiques du site de votre lien sont finement menées !

Comment: La référence du dernier paragraphe ne donne aucune source... L'auteur pourrait avoir tout inventé.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi j'ai ajouté le lien vers l'atilf qui le confirme.