# Why do you need to say "l'un de nos amis" instead of "un de nos amis"?

Tags: grammaire, articles

> Si elle n'arrivait pas à me trouver, je suis sûr qu'elle aurait cherché à joindre **l'un de nos amis**.

Why do you need to place *l'* (contraction of *le*) before *un*? I notice that when you say "*un de ces jours*", you don’t say "*l'un de ces jours*". So I wonder when you need to add *l'* and when not?

Comment: You do not **need to** to have the definite article here, it is just a possibility that denotes a formal way of writing/speaking. Note you can have it in "*l'un de ces jours*" just as well. I expect the use of the optional definite article here could be justified by the determining role played by the presence of the demonstrative "*ces*" or the possessive "*nos*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux sont utilisables: *un des / l'un des , une des, l'une des*

Il y a deux notions:

- un des = un parmi plusieurs
- l' (le) = celui-ci justement

Grevisse, relayé par [Etudes littéraires](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic43689-un-des-plus-ou-lun-des-plus.html) :

> Dans une construction avec « l’un », un a une valeur de pronom que le
>   « l’ », toujours facultatif, peut renforcer. Le L’ de l’un a une
>   vocation euphonique (et littéraire). L’emploi, note Grevisse, est ici
>   pronominal (« le un »... élidé en l’un) et indéfini (l’un des...). L’
>   **accentue**, dans la langue « soutenue », le caractère pronominal de ce
>   qui est d’ordinaire un déterminant numéral.

Comment: N'est-ce pas la même discussion que « on » vs « l'on », avec les mêmes réponses de la part des linguistes ?

Comment: @Chop pas franchement, car  dans le cas de l'on : on part de l'homme => l'on, puis on. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17339/lorsquon-ou-lorsque-lon/17340#17340  .  Ici, c'est une accentuation sur un indéfini.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que l'on pourrait remplacer « l'un de nos amis » par « Le premier de nos amis ». Mais on ne dit jamais « Le un de nos amis » car il ne faut pas oublier que devant une voyelle ou un *h* muet l'élision (apostrophe) est de rigueur.

Comment: « Le premier de nos amis » n'a pas le même sens que « l'un de nos amis ». « Le premier  de nos amis » désigne un ami spécifique (le premier), « l'un de nos amis » désigne n'importe lequel de nos amis.