# "Quoique l'on" ou "quoiqu'on"

Tags: usage

Un "l" peut être ajouté devant "on" pour l'euphonie, qui évite la collision de deux voyelles successives. Exemple: "si on va" devient "si l'on va". Il ne s'agit pas de correction grammaticale mais d'améliorer la prononciation.

Cependant, dans le cas de "quoique", je ne suis pas sûr que l'ajout d'un "l" améliore la prononciation. "Quoiqu'on" se prononce bien donc "quoique l'on" ne dénote-t-il pas plutôt un langage affecté qu'un bon langage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Un "l" peut être ajouté devant "on" pour l'euphonie.

Formuler les choses ainsi manque de nuance. Le « l » qu'on rencontre parfois devant « on » n'est pas toujours euphonique. Ceci a souvent été dit ici<sup>1</sup>, alors j'ai essayé de trouver une autre source, voici ce que dit Grevisse :

> *On*, ancien cas sujet du nom *homme*, a pris peu à peu un sens indéterminé.
>   [...]
>   En tant que nom, *on* était souvent, dans l'ancienne langue, précédé de l'article *l*. Devenu nominal, il a conservé la faculté de prendre cet article. *L'on* est, dans la langue écrite, un substitut « élégant » de *on* ; il n'est pas d'usage dans la langue parlée, sauf parfois chez les personnes qui surveillent leur langue et parlent comme elles écrivent. Selon une règle **traditionnelle**<sup>2</sup> des grammairiens, *l'on* est demandé, pour l'euphonie, après, *et, ou, ou, qui, que, quoi, si,* et parfois aussi après *lorsque*. En fait les auteurs en usent, en ceci, assez librement, soit qu'ils mettent le simple *on* là où la « règle » demanderait l'on, soit qu'ils emploient *l'on* après d'autres mots que ceux que la « règle » indique.

Dans le cas de *que* et ses composés, ajouter un *l'*, ce n'est pas en fait une question d'euphonie puisqu'il n'y a pas de hiatus (comme ce serait le cas par exemple avec *si* ou *ou*) vu que je ne pense pas que beaucoup de francophones prononceraient [kəɔ̃] à la place de [kɔ̃].

- "Quoiqu'on" → [kwakɔ̃] : je prononce 2 syllabes.
- "quoique l'on" → [kwakəlɔ̃] : je prononce 3 syllabes.

L'ajout d'une syllabe supplémentaire à mon avis complique la prononciation, car ça ajoute une syllabe.

La raison pour laquelle certains préfèrent employer *l'on* à la place de *on* après *que* est donné sur [Druide](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/et-lon) : « c'est pour éviter la syllabe malsonnante *qu'on* ». En effet, en français, le son [kɔ̃] a une connotation négative car il est associé au nom « con ».

Pour répondre à la question :

> "quoique l'on" ne dénote-t-il pas plutôt un langage affecté qu'un bon langage?

Même si moi je dis « qu'on » je ne parlerais pas personnellement de langage affecté dans le cas de personnes disant « que l'on » mais d'une perception différente de la syllabe [kɔ̃], ce qui ne relève pas nécessairement de l'affectation.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Voir [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1044/358) et [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17340/358), et peut-être d'autres, il y a de nombreux doublons sur la question.</sub>  
  <sub><sup>2</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

J'aurais tendance à penser qu'il faut regarder le mot suivant. Je m'explique:

> Quoiqu'on en dise / Quoique l'on en dise (ici je préfère la première version)
>
> Quoiqu'on fasse / Quoique l'on fasse (ici je préfère la seconde version)

Peut-être que quand le mot suivant commence par une voyelle, *Quoique l'on* devient une mauvaise option (peut-être parce qu'il y a un mot supplémentaire et que ça sonne un peu trop "long" à l'oreille).

Comment: C'est corrigé, merci.

Answer (score -1):

L'usage de cette lettre avant « on » est considéré dans « **I** » et « **II** » ci-dessous.

**I**

**a)** Le l euphonique, aussi appelé l explétif se place avant le pronom « on » dans certain cas, mais dans la langue moderne seulement si le l'utilisateur du langage le désire. Cette lettre n'a aucune fonction grammaticale et le plus souvent la raison avancée pour cette insertion est l'euphonie.

Son emploi a été recommandé et l'est encore parfois dans les cas suivants mais peu utilisé sauf chez les utilisateurs qui lisent suffisamment ([réf.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%E2%80%99on) : L’emploi de « l’on » au lieu de « on » est considéré comme soutenu, littéraire.)  :

- **hiatus (deux voyelles phonétiques)** en particulier après les locution suivantes : et, ou, où, à qui, à quoi, qui, que, quoi, pourquoi, si, lorsque

  - On ira à la plage puis l'on fera un feu.
  - Il voulait savoir pourquoi l'on ne ferait pas ça. ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pourquoi+l%27on+ne%2Cpourquoi+on+ne&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpourquoi%20l%27%20on%20ne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpourquoi%20on%20ne%3B%2Cc0))
- **redoublement désagréable d’une syllabe**

  - Sur le pont d'Avignon, l'on y danse
  - Il faut d'abord que l'on compte les mots.

Son emploi n'a pas été fait dans les cas suivants :

- **avant « dont »** On fait alors la liaison (ce don-ton)

  - Ce  dont on connait le nom est catalogué.
- **avant un mot commençant par l** pour éviter une *allitération* (répétition de consonnes)

  - Le jour qu'on leur a assigné est le vendredi.

**b)** *Le Bon Usage*, 14e ed. § 754, met en garde les étudiants du français.

> Pour l'euphonie les grammairiens conseillent d'éviter l'on après « dont » ou
>   devant un mot commençant par [l] et de l'employer après que si la syllabe qui suit
>   est [kɔ̃]. Mais, si la première prescription (après « dont ») est assez bien respectée,
>   les manquements aux deux autres sont loin d'être rares :
>
> - Ses yeux noirs où L'ON LISAIT une parfaite assurance (BARRÉS, Dérac., p. 259).
> - Il ne possède rien même si L'ON LUI donne (JAMMES, Clairières dans le ciel, p. 121).
> - Que l'on prend, que L'ON LAISSE (VALÉRY, « Mon Faust », p. 163).
> - Lieu où L'ON LOGE des bœufs (Ac. 1932, s. v. étable). [Auparavant l'Ac. utilisait la formule sont logés.]
> - Et telle est son insistance QU'ON COMPREND [...] (MAURIAC, Vie de Jésus, p. 184).
> - Ce QU'ON CONCÉDERAIT à la vérité (CAMUS, Homme révolté, p. 233).

**c)** Assez souvent, on trouve que la  motivation pour écrire « que l'on » au lieu de « qu'on » serait du type suivant ([réf.](https://parlez-vous-french.com/qu-on-ou-que-lon/)).

> En effet, en français, le son [kɔ̃] (qu’on) sonne mal et a une connotation négative car il est associé au nom “con”.
>   Le nom “con” est un mot vulgaire utilisé généralement comme insulte dans les pays francophones. Il désigne une personne stupide, désagréable, naïve.
>   Il est donc préférable d’écrire « ce que l’on dit« au lieu de « ce qu’on dit » pour éviter ce son mal sonnant.

Si le mot « con » est bien un mot vulgaire, ce type de motivation doit être, à mon avis, banni de la liste des  possibles critères pour le l euphonique.
D'abord il ne s'agit plus d'un l « euphonique » et ensuite si l'on introduit cette norme dans le langage il n'y a pas de fin à la liste des cas qui vont susciter un soucis d'égale discrimination. Prenons-en quelques uns ;

- cette manie qu'ont les gens de … • ce qu'on leur a dit … • si un compte le prouve … • c'est vrai qu'on la tourne en bourrique …

Ce qui est vrai pour le mot « con » ne l'est pas moins pour le mot « cul », qui, lui, est même intégralement incarné  phonétiquement par une lettre de l'alphabet. Vis-à-vis de ce phénomène parasitique, il n'y a pas d'autre attitude que celle de miser sur la justesse de l'esprit pur, que l'équivoque ne détourne pas du droit chemin et espérer pour les générations futures que l'évolution de la langue tende vers l'épuration de celle-ci.¹

**II**

Il existait un emploi que l'on ne peut pas imputer à l'euphonie, celui  de l utilisé en début de phrase avant « on »

On dit de  cet emploi qu'il est  vieilli ;

- On parle de tout.  (et non : L’on parle de tout.)

Cependant, il n'existe pas une véritable proscription ; on relève ceci dans le Robert des difficultés du français.

> Cet emploi n'est jamais obligatoire et paraît souvent affecté, surtout en début de phrase, où il ne correspond à aucune nécessité phonétique.

Selon les mots de certaines personnes, en particulier une qui publie dans [Études littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic26388-peuton-commencer-une-phrase-par-lon-dit-que.html)
« cependant, encore une fois, il n'est pas formellement proscrit... Et tout pédantisme mis à part, même sans utilité phonétique, ce n'est pas forcément désagréable à l'oreille… »

**III**

Je crois qu'il ne faille pas parler d'affectation dans cette pratique d'ajouter un « l », ni en ce qui concerne son origine ni en ce qui concerne sa perpétuation jusqu'au temps présent.
Son origine remonte au  XVIIe siècle ;

> [réf.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%E2%80%99on) : les grammairiens y ont vu un usage euphonique servant à éviter un hiatus ; ils l’ont recommandé après « et », « ou », « qui », « que », « quoi » ou « si ». Ces recommandations ont été peu suivies : aujourd’hui, on entend couramment les deux formes (« si on veut » et « si l’on veut »). « L’on » doit donc être traité comme une variante stylistique soutenue.

Si dans un soucis de polir la langue les grammairiens du XVIIe siècle y ont apporté un raffinement à la limite du nécessaire, cette mesure n'est pas moins initialement motivée dans le domaine pur de la linguistique. Si au cours des âge, cette mesure, qui initialement ne peut avoir eu un plein effet que dans les milieux des lettrés et dans les sections connexes de la population, apparait de nos jours comme ayant perdu beaucoup de sa force, il ne faut pas négliger que la langue a changé, que sa perception est quelque peu différente et il ne faut pas négliger non plus que l'alphabétisation massive qui a pris place depuis ces origines a permis a une population beaucoup moins susceptible à la tradition d'accéder à la publication et ainsi d'introduire une divergence importante. Ainsi, l'interprétation du phénomène de semi adhérence comme étant une possible affectation de certains ne tient pas : ceux qui y adhèrent toujours, et ils sont encore nombreux sont toujours sujets au puissant effet de la formation, de la tradition, alors que ceux qui au contraire ne suivent pas, pourraient être divertis de cette voie par les perceptions nouvelles que l'on a de la langue, de sa prononciation en particulier.

¹<sub>, en pensant peut être à *[Satyre XVII.—L'équivoque](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Boileau_-_%C5%92uvres_po%C3%A9tiques/Satires/Satire_XII)* de Boileau, qui nous ouvre à l'universalité de ce phénomène et son emprise sur l'être humain.</sub>