# Français relâché et emploi du subjonctif (présent/passé). Est-ce une afféterie ?

Tags: subjonctif

Dans du français un peu relâché voire peu soigné, est-ce que l'emploi du subjonctif manque de naturel ou a l'air guindé et affété (stilted en anglais) ? Doit-on éviter l'emploi du subjonctif dans un tel contexte ?
Par exemple, faut-il dire :

> **On doit partir** ou encore mieux **Faut partir** au lieu de **Il faut qu'on parte**

?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27air+pas+naturel%2Cpas+l%27air+naturel&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20l%27%20air%20naturel%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LPH J'ai actualisé la question. Merci.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ces changements dans ces deux mots, que l'on reconnais et qui correspondent au contexte : guindé, affecté.

Comment: Je te déconseille fortement l'emploi du mot *affété* qui est non seulement **vieilli** mais **péjoratif** (peut signifié *efféminé*). *Affecté*, *maniéré* et *affété* sont des quasi synonymes, *maniéré* est le plus courant, *affecté* plus rare et donc de niveau de langue plus élevé, quant à *affété* il est considéré comme vieilli par tous les dictionnaires. (Pour résumer brièvement la réponse que j'allais publiée au moment où tu as effacé ta question).

Comment: Un mot sur "affété".  Cet adjectif est rarissime, il s'emploie beaucoup moins que le nom "afféterie".  Je reformulerais ta question en : "Français relâché et emploi du subjonctif (présent/passé). Est-ce une afféterie?"

Comment: J’ajouterais que si c'est *stilted* que tu cherches à traduire par « affété » ça ne convient pas. *stilted* c'est « guindé »,  si tu veux en employer un autre tu peux envisager aussi « compassé » ou « ampoulé ».

Comment: @Laure Je m'excuse de l'inconvénient. Je viens de poser de nouveau la question. Je l'ai effacée initialement parce que j'ai pensé que c'était élémentaire. Mais finalement j'ai réalisé que c'est une question intéressante.

Comment: À mon avis un meilleur titre serait : « L'emploi du subjonctif (présent/passé) en français relâché est-il systématiquement perçu comme affecté ? ». J'admets ne pas connaître le terme _afféterie_, je ne savais pas si c'était une erreur ou le nom d'une figure de style que je ne connais pas...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'emploi du subjonctif ne relève pas toujours du langage soutenu, il est parfois obligatoire, comme après « il faut que  ». Cependant l'effet perçu peut aussi dépendre du verbe employé et de l'écart phonétique (et/ou orthographique) avec d'autres temps plus employés que le subjonctif.
La forme du subjonctif présent « parte » garde le radical de l'infinitif et à l'oreille on pourrait avoir tendance à oublier que c'est un subjonctif. Prenons un verbe régulier en -er (ce que la grammaire française appelle souvent un verbe du 1<sup>er</sup> groupe) :  *Il faut qu'on marche*.  La forme du subjonctif présent est exactement la même que celle du présent de l'indicatif, l'« effet subjonctif » n'est pas perçu de façon explicite.

Prenons maintenant un verbe comme « faire » :  *il faut qu'on fasse les courses*. Dans ce cas le subjonctif modifie le radical et la forme du verbe est moins fréquente (phonétiquement et graphiquement) dans le langage courant ; la distance peut la faire ressentir comme plus soutenue. La distance serait encore plus grande, il me semble, si nous employions la 1<sup>re</sup> pers. du plur. : *il faut que nous fassions*.  Plus la langue est loin de nous, moins elle nous parait familière, donc plus soutenue.

- Langage soutenu :
  Il faut que l'on parte*.
- Langage courant :
  Il faut qu'on parte.
  On doit partir.
  Nous devons partir.
  Il faut partir.
- Langage familier (sujet non exprimé) :
  Faut partir.
  Faut qu'on parte.

  ---

*See those [question and answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1029/358).

Comment: Merci. Pour le français familier : Y faut partir ? (y au lieu de pronom neutre il)

Comment: La chute du /l/ est tellement courante à l'oral que je placerait (opinion personnelle!) cette prononciation au niveau du langage courant.

Comment: "il faut qu'on parte" n'a rien de soutenu pour moi.

Comment: @Dimitris  _Y faut partir_ est aussi valable pour le cas familier, ou encore _Y faut qu'on parte_. Le "il" est souvent mangé, pour devenir "i"

Comment: @petitrien Tout à fait. Je rectifie.

Comment: @Dimitris Je ne pense pas que *y faut partir* soit très usité, il est beaucoup plus courant de carrément laisser tomber le pronom personnel dans le cas présent . Par contre « il » devient « y »  quand on ne peut pas du tout supprimer le sujet. Très fréquent avec « il y a » par exemple. « **y'a** qu'moi qu'ai raison ! ». Tout ça reste bien sûr du langage parlé.

Comment: Je classifierais *nous devons partir* comme langage soutenu.

Comment: @jlliagre On aurait-il déjà supplanté nous ? mouais, possible. Est-ce que tu dirais aussi que « je dois partir est soutenu » ?

Comment: 1. Le *nous* clitique a essentiellement disparu du français oral spontané. *Nous* est en revanche bien sûr toujours présent dans d'autres rôles où il n'a pas de substitut : *Nous, on le garde pour nous*. 2. Je ne dirais pas que *je dois partir* est uniquement soutenu. C'est aussi du français courant, plus soutenu cependant que *il faut que je parte* et bien sûr *faut que je parte* qui doivent être les tournures les plus habituelles à l'oral.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord sur la distance qui ferait moins utiliser le subjonctif. La façon la plus naturelle de dire « nous devons partir » dans la langue de tous les jours, c'est « faut qu'on y aille ».

Answer (score 4):

Le subjonctif imparfait (et le plus-que-parfait) n'est plus utilisé que dans la langue très soutenue. L'utiliser à l'oral est très recherché et plutôt affecté¹ ou snob. Dans la langue parlée normale, même plutôt soutenue, on le remplace par le subjonctif présent (subjonctif passé pour le plus-que-parfait).

Le subjonctif présent (et le passé) sont utilisés à tous les niveaux de langues. Un locuteur natif peut se tromper dans certaines constructions grammaticales inhabituels ou avec certains verbes irréguliers, mais pas ne va utiliser l'indicatif à la place du subjonctif dans la langue relâchée.

Il y a au moins un cas courant où les francophones ont tendance à utiliser le subjonctif au lieu de l'indicatif : après *après que*. En général *après que* devrait être suivi de l'indicatif, et la plupart des prescriptivistes refusent l'utilisation du subjonctif. Mais l'utilisation du subjonctif est une faute courante (en plus d'être correcte dans certains cas, et elle finira sûrement par devenir admise officiellement). La plupart des gens perçoivent l'utilisation du subjonctif comme une faute si on attire leur attention dessus. Voir [« Avant que » et « après que » : indicatif ou subjonctif?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/avant-que-et-apr%c3%a8s-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif) pour plus de détails.

Prenons l'exemple de la question. Sans contexte particulier, la forme soutenue la plus naturelle est « Il faut que nous partions. ». La forme familière la plus naturelle est « Faut qu'on y aille. » ([fo.kɔ̃.n‿jaj]) (« y aller » signifie « partir » dans le langage courant). Le subjonctif n'est pas un obstacle, même avec un verbe irrégulier.

¹  Pas *affété* : l'[affèterie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aff%C3%A8terie) est contraire au bon goût, l'[affectation](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affectation) (sens B.1) manque seulement de naturel.