# Is there a difference between "qu'on" and "que l'on"?

Tags: grammaire, euphonie

I would like to know if there is a difference between, qu'on and que l'on.

I read other answers, and it seems to me that the meaning is the same. In a phrase like

> C'est souvent le week-end que l'on fait la grasse matinée.

Could I also say

> C'est souvent le week-end qu'on fait la grasse matinée.

Is the second one grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are equally grammatical. the ***l'*** is optional and a remnant of the definite article from the time when ***on*** was still seen as an equivalent of "***homme***".

> C'est souvent le weekend que **l'homme** fait la grasse matinée.

On the other hand, a pronoun doesn't need any article so "***qu'on** fait la grasse matinée*" is fine. The article is more common when it is feared that the audience might hear ***con*** instead of ***qu'on***.

See [“L’on y danse”: why the article “l’ ”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/l-on-y-danse-why-the-article-l)